# Error using getText() and attaching it to my spinner

Tags: java, android

I wanted to get the text from EditText and attach it to my spinner.First I tried this:

```
private EditText edit;    
private EditText editt;
String team1 = edit.getText().toString();
String team2 = editt.getText().toString();
```

and got a `NullPointerException`.

I formatted my code as:

```
private EditText t1;
private EditText t2;
String team1 = ((t1 != null) && (t1.getText().toString().trim().size()) > 0)
                 ? t1.getText()
                 : 0;
String team2=  ((t2 != null) && (t2.getText().toString().trim().size()) > 0)
                 ? t2.getText()
                 : 0;
```

I got an other error saying that the above condition is always null.

[image: These are the errors I am facing.]

Comment: where is findViewById in your code?

Comment: Did you found the View's in layout on your activity?

Comment: Post the *Logcat* error.

Comment: Did you initialize all your variables?

Comment: Im suprised your code builds. it looks like you are setting a string to an integer value

Comment: And String doesn't even have method `size()` it should be `length()`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First** you should initialize your `View` objects in activity class by calling `findViewById(R.id.editTextId)`.
**Secondly** `String` object does not have `.size()` method. If you want to know the length of this string you should use `.length()` method.
**Third point** the int value `0` can not be assigned to a String object.

```
EditText t1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextId);
String team1 = ((t1 != null) && (t1.getText().toString().trim().length()) > 0)? 
                t1.getText().toString() : "0";
```

Comment: I think `t1.getText()` should also read `t1.getText().toString()`. Hes got so many errors, its hard to spot them all. :)

Answer (score 2):

You are not creating your views, you must initiate them by using `findViewById` or programmatically, using `EditText edit = new EditText(context)`

Ex:

```
EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_id);
String text = edit.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you use `findViewById` for the `EditTexts`?

Comment: Yes, I did use find by view id.

Answer (score 0):

`EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_id);`

And please use this:

`t1.getText().toString().trim().length()`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to some comments, if your compileSdk is at least 26, you can also remove the casting when using findViewById.

so:

```
EditText edit = findViewById(R.id.edit_text_id);
```